# Problems viewing Collada files in Gazebo-ROS

Tags: ros, gazebo, gazebo-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have followed the tutorial to insert a Collada `.dae` file into Gazebo, so that my world file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<sdf version="1.4">
<world name="test_world">
    <include>
        <uri>model://sun</uri>
    </include>
    <include>
        <uri>model://ground_plane</uri>
    </include>
    
<model name="duck">
    <pose>0 0 0  0 0 0</pose>
    <static>true</static>
    <link name="body">
        <visual name="visual">
            <geometry>
                <mesh><uri>file://duck.dae</uri></mesh>
            </geometry>
        </visual>
    </link>
</model>
</world>
</sdf>
```

If I run `gazebo test_world.world` I can see the duck. However, if I create the following launch file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<launch>

<include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="world_name"   value="$(find my_package)/models/test_world.world" />
    <arg name="use_sim_time" value="true" />
    <arg name="debug"        value="false" />
    <arg name="gui"          value="true" />
</include>
</launch>
```

The duck is not displayed in Gazebo, although I can see the element exists in the left-hand pannel. I have seen other people with my problem, and tried many things, but I cannot make it work.

Should the `.dae` and `.world` files be in a specific folder? Any help is appreciated! (I'm using Gazebo 4.1.3 with ROS Indigo).

**UPDATE:** After applying the accepted answer, this is the final state (note that `file://` has changed to `model://`)

Launch file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<launch>
<include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="world_name"   value="$(find my_package)/models/test_world.world" />
    <arg name="use_sim_time" value="true" />
    <arg name="debug"        value="false" />
    <arg name="gui"          value="true" />
</include>
</launch>
```

World file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<sdf version="1.4">
<world name="test_world">
    <include>
        <uri>model://sun</uri>
    </include>
    <include>
        <uri>model://ground_plane</uri>
    </include>

<model name="duck">
    <pose>0 0 0  0 0 0</pose>
    <static>true</static>
    <link name="body">
        <visual name="visual">
            <geometry>
                <mesh><uri>model://duck.dae</uri></mesh>
            </geometry>
        </visual>
    </link>
</model>
</world>
</sdf>
```

And the folder structure is:

- my_package

  - models

    - test_world.world
    - duck.dae
  - lauch

    - test_launch.launch
  - CMakeLists.txt
  - package.xml

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212113/problems-viewing-collada-files-in-gazebo-ros/) by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1305 on 2015-06-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess you need to add an export to your  package.xml

```
  <export>
    <!-- You can specify that this package is a metapackage here: -->
    <!-- <metapackage/> -->

    <!-- Other tools can request additional information be placed here -->
    <gazebo_ros gazebo_model_path="${prefix}/models"/> 
  </export>
```

And:

```
  <run_depend>gazebo_ros</run_depend>
  <build_depend>gazebo_ros</build_depend>
```

And in CMakeLists:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED gazebo_ros)
```

so the model path "models" inside your package is found by gazebo.

If you are learning SDF now, I guess I am sure that you might also have to learn URDF
because SDF is not supported by ROS tools like robot state publisher. (Just a hint) ;-)

UPDATE:
I have a model myself inside the directory of my package with dae.
I inserted it with gazebo and saved the world file with it.

```
<model name='hills'>
  <static>1</static>
  <link name='link'>
    <collision name='collision'>
      <geometry>
        <mesh>
          <uri>model://hills/mesh/hills.dae</uri>
        </mesh>
      </geometry>
      <max_contacts>10</max_contacts>
      <surface>
        <bounce/>
        <friction>
          <ode/>
        </friction>
        <contact>
          <ode/>
        </contact>
      </surface>
    </collision>
    <visual name='visual_1'>
      <pose>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
      <cast_shadows>0</cast_shadows>
      <geometry>
        <mesh>
          <uri>model://hills/mesh/hills.dae</uri>
        </mesh>
      </geometry>
      <material>
        <script>
          <uri>model://hills/materials/scripts</uri>
          <uri>model://hills/materials/textures</uri>
          <name>vrc/grass</name>
        </script>
      </material>
    </visual>
    <velocity_decay>
      <linear>0</linear>
      <angular>0</angular>
    </velocity_decay>
    <self_collide>0</self_collide>
    <kinematic>0</kinematic>
    <gravity>1</gravity>
  </link>
  <pose>5 -5 0 0 -0 0</pose>
</model>
```

It lies in a subfolder

models

```
-hills
 -materials
 -scripts
 -textures
 -mesh
   -hills.dae
 model.config
 model.sdf
```

Regards,

Christian

---

Originally posted by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) with karma: 1376 on 2015-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2015-06-25**:
I'm afraid that is not working, the same results. Cannot see the duck when I roslaunch the file.

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-06-25**:
maybe a catkin_make could also help ... to publish the path...

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2015-06-25**:
@cyborg-x1 Well, by manually creating the model at `~/.gazebo` I was able to do what you mention. I saved the world and now it works from the launch file. However, I depend on the file being at `~/.gazebo`, which is not very satisfactory.

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2015-06-25**:
@cyborg-x1 I changed the `<uri>model://duck/meshes/duck.dae</uri>` by package://my_package/models/duck.dae but it does not work. How can I refer to a model in a package? Thank you!!

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-06-25**:
that is the export I mentioned it will add the models path in your package to the gazebo one ... and it should find your model ... it does for me ...

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-06-25**:
Check the insert tab of gazebo if you find your path there.

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2015-06-25**:
I do not know what I am doing wrong, but it does not work. In theory, the only thing missing to what I did in the original post is the line addition to the package.xml, are you sure about it?

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-06-25**:
I do not know when and where it does create that link but you could try to remove devel and build folders and execute catkin_make again... actually that should probably add the folder so you should see any models below it in the Gazebo Insert Tab or at least the path. And source devel/setup.bash

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-06-25**:
ok got it you need to make it dependend to gazebo_ros package ...

```
  <run_depend>gazebo_ros</run_depend>
  <build_depend>gazebo_ros</build_depend>
```

And in CMakeLists:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED gazebo_ros)
```

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2015-06-25**:
At the end I have solved created the URDF from the mesh with the help of a colleague. But that SDF problem is actually killing me!

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-06-25**:
This should work now I tried it with a new package. Rebuild my workspace and started gazebo, and the path shows up there in my Insert List, even if it is empty

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2015-06-25**:
Yes!! That's it, the CMakeLists.txt and dependencies addition. Can you please update your answer to mark it as accepted?

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-06-25**:
You should be able to accept it, you are the guy which asked, I can't I am not a moderator.